# What's the difference between brand and company?

Tags: difference, word-difference

I find them confusing. Please make me clear about these.

Comment: Usually you are expected to add some of your own research - if only out of curtesy, because we wouldn't want to repeat your research. Please edit your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Branding" is a relatively new English term; it refers to the way a company or organization establishes its "public image" in the marketplace.

A brand can be represented visually by logos and trademarks, but the essence of a brand consists in the *established reputation* of a company or organization. The brand exists in the "mind" of the public, if you will.

Comment: Good answer, but I would add that a single company can have many brands, whereas a brand is the property of only one company.

Answer (score 2):

A company is a group of people who do work in exchange for money. That company has a name, which may also be their *brand*. Pepsi is a company, they make a famous fizzy drink, the company is made up of thousands of people who sell their product. However, when someone asks me if I want a Pepsi, I know what drink they're talking about because the Pepsi company has been very good at promoting their brand.

The Pepsi *brand* is recognised by its logo, its famous blue/white/red colour scheme, its curly font, and the taste of their drink.

So a brand is a look or style that I associate with a company.